# Continued fraction with alternative signs

Tags: continued-fractions

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers.
We can define a formal finite continued fraction as usual

$$[a_0]=a_0,[a_0,a_1]=a_0+\frac{1}{[a_0]},\cdots,[a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n]=a_0+\frac{1}{[a_1,\cdots,a_n]}.$$

If all $a_n\ge0$, then by Seidel-Stern Theorem and Stern-Stolz Theorem, the formal continued fraction converges if and only if $\sum a_n=\infty$.

What about the sequence with alternative sign: $a_n a_{n+1}<0$ for all $n\ge0$? Is there some conditions that guarantee the *well-definiteness* and the convergence of $[a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n]$?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a complete answer but Pringsheim’s Theorem says that $|a_i| \ge 2$ is sufficient for convergence. See [DLFM 1.12](http://dlmf.nist.gov/1.12).

Comment: Could you move your comment to an answer? It is good enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer but Pringsheim’s Theorem says that $|a_i|\ge 2$ is sufficient for convergence. See [DLFM 1.12](http://dlmf.nist.gov/1.12).